# AspectJ Load Time Weaving For Any Minecraft Forge Mod Installed

Tags: java, minecraft, aspectj, minecraft-forge

**Context:**
I've been working on a fork for the RecipeStages mod https://github.com/DrainBread/RecipeStages/tree/1.16

The purpose of my modification is to allow this mod to work with any other mod that adds custom recipes and/or use custom and vanilla working stations.

After attempting different solutions, I found that it would be easier to intercept the invocation of the IRecipe assemble() method implementation to verify if a recipe can be crafted. To do so, I'm using AspectJ.

However I found that the aspect that I developed only works when the method is invoked within the RecipeStages mod and nowhere else.

**The Question:**
Is it possible to use AspectJ to intercept the invocation of this method across all of the mods installed? if so, how?

From what I've learned about AspectJ (which isn't much, this is my first time ever using it), this would be possible if Load Time Weaving was enabled for the entire project, which in my understanding, that would be the FML. If that is the case, would it be necessary to modify FML to allow this?

**What I have tried:**
Aside from AspectJ, I've tried using JavaAssist (with ProxyFactory), however that requires the "reconstruction" of the recipe object, which didn't go very well - since this is supposed to work with any mod, there is no way to recreate an object that is not declared in this project.
I have researched for a couple of days but there aren't a lot of info I could find related to AspectJ without Spring and using Gradle. No other mods to my knowledge use this approach either, so I'm starting to question if this is even viable.

Comment: My guess is that not AspectJ is the problem but class-loading. Probably whatever plugin you are developing is, when in action, isolated from other plugins in the same JVM with regard to the dependency tree of class-loaders. Furthermore, AspectJ cannot be used to change already loaded classes. Load-time weaving, as the name implies, can only instrument classes while they are being loaded.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you for your answer. Although I don't fully understand how FML loads the .jars into the game, I suspect that this might be the problem as well. I'm currently researching the FML docs to see if there is any Mod Lifecyle event I can use instead of weaving. In the meantime, would post-compile weaving be viable in this scenario, assuming the FML loads the other .jars before mine?

Comment: Compile-time or post-compile weaving require that you have access to what you want to weave during build time. This is even less likely to work with binaries not under your control during runtime. Why what you want is difficult or even impossible, is easy to understand: If your plugin is part of a public platform, the owners of course want to avoid you hacking the main application or other modules. What you want to do at first glance looks like a hack, though. So good luck with that.

Comment: @kriegaex makes sense, I didn't see it that way at first. I'll try and rely on methods supported by the FML instead to find a new solution. Thanks again!